# html file upload control not updating textbox field in IE7 and IE8

Tags: html, file, internet-explorer-8, upload, internet-explorer-7

One of our QA guys here has found an issue with IE7/IE8 that I cannot seem to find a solution for.

A basic file upload control renders in IE7/8 with a browse button and a textbox.

If the file path is longer than the textbox, you can't scroll to the end of the path. Well you can scroll using the left/right arrows or the home/end keys but the textbox is not updated / does not move to the correct cursor position.

Any ideas why?

All other browsers, FF, Google, IE9 is fine.

I also tried hiding the real file upload control and 'mimic' the control with a custom button / textbox - on click event of this custom button, the file uploads click event is fired but IE does not upload the file like that.

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The file upload control has very limited functionality, especially in older browsers, even when it comes to CSS/scripting.

There is very little reason for the user to be able to see this information anyway since it is simply a path to a file being uploaded. Since they selected this file from a file dialog, there is no to real reason to be able to edit this information either.

I'm not sure if that qualifies as to "why", but it does explain why not much attention has been paid to this type of control. Yeah, it may be different than other browser versions, but I can hardly see this being a serious QA issue unless there is a specific requirement for this.

Comment: Thanks for the quick comment, and I totally agree with you. It's just that the QA team has raised it as an issue they found different between different browsers. I was happy to close the issue but wanted to make sure I didn't close an issue that had a viable/easy hotfix/solution.